# Open balls centered at infinity in the extended reals?

Tags: real-numbers

Is an open ball of some radius $\delta >0$ defined at $+\infty$, if $+\infty$ is in the extended reals?  (I have the same question for $-\infty$.)

Comment: Please explain how you define this open ball centered at $+\infty$ and also you mean "is the open ball a subset of the extended reals?"

Answer (score 1):

No, you would need to define a distance between $+\infty$ and the other points in order to define what an open ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $+\infty$ is.

Comment: Are you sure? http://www.math.harvard.edu/~pflueger/math1b/limits.pdf

Comment: @jackjacob How would that contradict what I said?